# How to split an URL into two parts based on /

Tags: regex, powershell, sharepoint, split, substring

I want to split an URl into two parts based on number of `/`

For example

Input : `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/wizard`

now after splitting based on 4th `/`, two strings will be

Output1: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions`
Output2: `ask/wizard`

Comment: Why even split it? You have a fixed first part, just use the substring starting at the number of characters of the fixed part till the end of the input.

Comment: @Seth first part may varry depending upon the input. So the only way is to split based on number of "\"

Comment: So just split by either the slash or find the fourth slash and use a substring? Splitting based on `\` is also pretty easy as it's not part of any of the example URLs. ;)

Comment: you have not mentioned how to determine where the split will be. so ... how do you decide where to make that split? ///// have you looked at the result of `[uri]$Test = https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/wizard`? the `$Test.Segments` property looks useful ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 1):

The `.split()` method as well as the `-split` operator can limit the number of splits.

So split into 5 parts, rejoin [0..3] for `$Output1` and get zero based index [4] for `$Output2`

```
## Q:\Test\2019\04\30\SO_5519104.ps1

$URL = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/wizard'
$Output1 = $URL.Split('/',5)[0..3] -join '/'
$Output2 = $URL.Split('/',5)[4]
```

---

```
> Get-Variable Output[12]

Name                           Value
----                           -----
Output1                        https://stackoverflow.com/questions
Output2                        ask/wizard
```

Answer (score 1):

here is yet another way to do the job. [*grin*] what it does ...

- uses the `[uri]` type accelerator to coerce the URL string into a `[uri]` object
- grabs the last `$Part_2_Segments` from that and joins them back into a string
- removes the `$Output_2` from the original string
- removes the leftover trailing `\` or `/` from the end of `$Output_1`
  thanks to LotPings for the alert about that. [*grin*]
- displays the two resulting strings

here's the code ...

```
$URL_String = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/wizard'

$Part_2_Segments = 2

$Output_2 = -join ([uri]$URL_String).Segments[-$Part_2_Segments..-1]
$Output_1 = $URL_String.Replace($Output_2, '').Trim('\/')

$Output_1
$Output_2
```

output ...

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions
ask/wizard
```

Comment: @LotPings - arg! i missed that one ... i'll go back and add a fix for it. thanks for the alert! [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/wizard" -replace '^([a-zA-Z:\.]*/[a-zA-Z:\.]*/[a-zA-Z:\.]*/[a-zA-Z:\.]*)/(.*$)', '$1'
```

=> https://stackoverflow.com/questions

```
"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/wizard" -replace '^([a-zA-Z:\.]*/[a-zA-Z:\.]*/[a-zA-Z:\.]*/[a-zA-Z:\.]*)/(.*$)', '$2'
```

=> ask/wizard

Comment: not working in powershell "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/wizard".Replace('^([a-zA-Z:\.]*/[a-zA-Z:\.]*/[a-zA-Z:\.]*/[a-zA-Z:\.]*)/(.*$)', '$2 ')